# Prove limit of function - need help

Tags: real-analysis

I have problem with this:
We have
$$
f:[a,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}
$$
and we know that in any range $[a,b]$, $f$ is limited. Morover $\lim_{x\to \infty}(f(x+1)-f(x))=1$.
Now what needs to be proved is:$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=1
$$

My idea was to use above limit which we know to derive following equation:
$$f(x+n)=f(x)+n+a_n$$
which I believe is correct. $a_n$ stands for sequence which should add whatever is needed to ensure that equation is correct. It should have finite limit, so $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(x+n)}{x+n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(x)+n+a_n}{x+n}=1$$

I still find this solution wanting. I don't know if it's totally wrong or just something needs to be added. My biggest concern is that all we know about $f$ is its behaviour in points like $x,x+1,\dots$. Now of course we also know for example what happens in $x+\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon+1,\dots$ but this creates a lot of sequences which does not have any obvious connections between each other. I don't know what to expect from limit in such case.

However, maybe if someone could comment my idea, I will have some clue what to do next.

Comment: "and we know that any range [a,b] is limited." what does that mean?

Comment: Umm, I should've written that $f$ is limited in any range [a,b]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $c>0$, $lim_{X\rightarrow +\infty}(f(x+1)-f(x))=1$ implies there exists $N_c: x>N_c$ implies that $1-c<f(x+1)-f(x)<1+c$. This implies for every $x\in [N_c,N_c+1]$ an every integer $l$,

$l(1-c)<f(x+l)-f(x+l-1)+f(x+l-1)+... f(x+1)-f(x)<l(1+c)$ this is equivalent to saying that $l(1-c)<f(x+l)-f(x)<l(1-c)$ this implies that

$l(1-c)/(x+l) + f(x)/(x+l)<f(x+l)/(x+l)<l(1+c)/(x+l)+f(x)/(x+l)$ Since $lim_{l\rightarrow +\infty}f(x)/(x+l)=0$ and $lim_{l\rightarrow +\infty}l(1-c)/(x+l)=1-c$ and $lim_{l\rightarrow +\infty}l(1+c)/(x+l)=1+c$, we deduce that there exists $l_0$ such that $l>l_0$ implies that $1-2c<f(x+l)/(x+l)<1+2c$ this is equivalent to saying that for $u>N_c+l_0+1, \mid f(u)/u-1\mid<4c$ a this shows the result. done