# If $ \lim_{x\to \infty} (f(x+1)-f(x))=1$, then $ \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}=1$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification, epsilon-delta, limsup-and-liminf

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a fuction such that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty} (f(x+1)-f(x))=1$. Is it true then that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}=1$?

I think it is and here is how I went about it. Let $\varepsilon>0$. Then there is some $\delta_\varepsilon>0$ such that $$1-\varepsilon < f(x)-f(x-1)<1+\varepsilon, \forall x>\delta_\varepsilon.$$
Thus, we may write the following inequalities for an $x> \delta_\epsilon$:
$$1-\varepsilon < f(x)-f(x-1)<1+\varepsilon\\
1-\varepsilon < f(x-1)-f(x-2)<1+\varepsilon\\    
\vdots\\
1-\varepsilon < f(\delta_\varepsilon+1)-f(\delta_\varepsilon)<1+\varepsilon$$
and after we sum these up we get that $$(x-\delta_\epsilon)(1-\epsilon)<f(x)-f(\delta_\varepsilon)<(x-\delta_\varepsilon)(1+\varepsilon), \forall x>\delta_\varepsilon.$$
This implies that $$\frac{f(\delta_\varepsilon)+(x-\delta_\varepsilon)(1-\varepsilon)}{x}<\frac{f(x)}{x}<\frac{f(\delta_\varepsilon)+(x-\delta_\varepsilon)(1+\varepsilon)}{x}, \forall x>\delta_\varepsilon.$$
If we take $\displaystyle\limsup_{x\to\infty}$, we get that $1-\varepsilon < \displaystyle\limsup_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}< 1+\varepsilon$, $\forall \varepsilon > 0$, so $\displaystyle\limsup_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}=1$. In the same way we get that $\displaystyle\liminf_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}=1$, so $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}=1$ as desired.

Is this proof correct? I am a bit unsure that I am taking that $\limsup$ correctly, even though I can't see why it could be wrong.

Comment: There should be another condition also that $f$ is bounded on every bounded interval.

Comment: @MartinR With the Stolz-Cesaro theorem I think that we can only show that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} f(n)/n=1$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh is there some counterexample without this condition? Where would my proof fail in that case?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1585995/42969

Comment: @PhoemueX: For $f(x) = \sqrt x $ is $\lim_{x\to \infty} (f(x+1)-f(x))=0$.

Comment: @PhoemueX $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x} = 0 \neq 1$$

Comment: I have closed this as duplicate. Please check linked question.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh thanks, the linked question indeed solves this is a similar way as I tried, but I wanted to understand why exactly my proof fails if $f$ is not bounded on every bounded interval (I saw the counterexample, but I am trying to understand exactly which part of my reasoning fails).

Comment: Also check the proof in that dupe target and see how the bounded nature of $f$ is used.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh: The question you linked is not a duplicate! The other question requests the function to be bounded on every finite interval.  This question has no such restriction.

Comment: The problem is that your argument works only when $x=\delta_{\epsilon} +n$ where $n$ is a positive integer. For it to work for all $x>\delta_{\epsilon} $ you will need $f$ to be bounded in $[\delta_{\epsilon}, \delta_{\epsilon} +1]$. I hope you understand the flaw.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts: please read all previous comments. I have mentioned that bounded nature is essential otherwise the result fails.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh: Just that a proof does not apply does not mean it proves a statement is true or false.  The statement is false, and the answer from 5xum is correct because it supplies a counter-example.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Ah, thanks, it does make sense, I felt that the way I tried to mimick what I would do for a sequence may be flawed. Now I understand, thank you very much!

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts: I think that the dupe target helped the asker (check their comments), but if you want to reopen I can post this in CURED chatroom to get reopened.

Comment: It's already reopened @ParamanandSingh

Comment: @ArcticChar: things happen so fast here and I am limited in my speed due to mobile device. :)

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: 1) For me as a reader of SE, it would be quite confusing: Following a [duplicate] link that deviates in non-minor details.  The answer to that other question cannot be applied to this one. 2) It's still preferable to have a proper answer (instead of having to dig into every  comment quere). Afterall, the two proofs (one confirming, one counter-example) are quite different. 3) It's nice that the TO found help and can proceed; but IIUC, SE is also about sharing information with "passive" readers.  Otherwise, all except the questions could be private.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts : Agree! I think the issue is resolved thanks to a reopening by 5xum.

Comment: Please don't use `\displaystyle` on question titles. See [Guidelines on good use of MathJax on question titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/888233).

Comment: You recieved 4 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, consider *accepting* the best answer and upvoting all useful answers you got. That's how the site works.

Comment: @5xum thanks for the tag, I had forgotten to accept an answer

Comment: Avoid using \displaystyle on title

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{[x]} + \lfloor x\rfloor;& x\notin \mathbb Z\\ \lfloor x\rfloor ; &x\in\mathbb Z\end{cases}$$

where $[x]$ denotes the fractional part of $x$, i.e. $[x]=x-\lfloor x\rfloor $.

Then the function satisfies your condition, since $f(x+1)-f(x)=1$ is true for all $x$. However, the limit $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}$$ does not exist, because the value of $f$ on every interval $[n, n+1]$ is unbounded.

Comment: thanks, so I guess that my proof fails here in this case: $\displaystyle \limsup_{x\to \infty}\frac{f(\delta_\epsilon)+(x-\delta_\epsilon)(1-\epsilon)}{x}$ (I don't really see any other place where it might). I thought that as $x\to \infty$ $f(\delta_\epsilon)$ would stay constant.

Comment: +1 for the fine counterexample.

Comment: @TheZone I think that's where your error is, yeah.

Answer (score 4):

In your proof you are implicitly assuming that $x$ is such that $x-\delta_\epsilon=n$ is an integer $n$, so you have some constraint on the specific value of $x$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$. In the example given by 5xum this means that the term $\frac{1}{[x]}=\frac{1}{[\delta_\epsilon]}$ which you assume to be fixed. If you want to allow general $x$ you would have to modify your inequality to $$\frac{f(x-\lfloor x-\delta_\epsilon\rfloor)+\lfloor x-\delta_\epsilon\rfloor(1-\epsilon)}{x}<\frac{f(x)}{x}<\frac{f(x-\lfloor x-\delta_\epsilon\rfloor)+\lfloor x-\delta_\epsilon\rfloor(1+\epsilon)}{x}, \forall x>\delta_\epsilon.$$
Now you have to assume that $f(x-\lfloor x-\delta_\epsilon \rfloor)$ is bounded $\forall  x>\delta_\epsilon$ in which case your proof would be correct. This however is not the case in 5xum's example.

Comment: thanks, now it is all really clear.

Comment: :P Wasn't sure it was already clear as you just assumed "I don't really see any other place where it might".

Answer (score 2):

Let
$
f(x)=
-\sin \left( \lfloor x\rfloor\cdot \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right) 
\cdot
 \cos\left( \lfloor x\rfloor\cdot \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right). 
$
Then
\begin{align}
f(x+1)-f(x)
=&
\sin \left( \lfloor x+1\rfloor\cdot \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right) 
\cdot
 \cos\left( \lfloor x+1\rfloor\cdot \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right)
-
\sin \left( \lfloor x\rfloor\cdot \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right) 
\cdot
 \cos\left( \lfloor x\rfloor\cdot \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right)
\\
=&+\sin\left((\lfloor x+1\rfloor - \lfloor x\rfloor)\cdot \dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)
\\
=& +\sin\left( 1\cdot \frac{\pi}{2} \right)
\\
=& 1
\end{align}
and  by $-1\leq f(x)=-
\sin \left( \lfloor x\rfloor\cdot \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right) 
\cdot
 \cos\left( \lfloor x\rfloor\cdot \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right)\leq +1$ we have
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=0.
$$

Comment: Your third equality should be $-\sin(\pi \lfloor x \rfloor)=0$ not $1$. Btw: $\sin(x)\cos(x)=\sin(2x)/2$ so actually $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.